# improper integral convergence at lower limit

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

what should be the condition on *m* and *n* for the function to converge?
$$
 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{m-1}x\cos^{n-1}xdx\,.
$$

For the given question, I chose a number $c$ in between $0-\pi/2$ and considered $m-1<0$ and tried to find the solution by dividing the function with 
$$
\frac{1}{x^{m-1}}, 
$$
which gave the condition for $m<0$, but the true solution is $m>0$ as per the answer key.

Answer (score 1):

First, look at the zero end.  Let $f(x) = \sin^{m-1} (x) \cos^{n-1}(x)$, and let $g(x) = x^{m-1}$.  Notice that
$$
    \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1
$$
so $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(x)\,dx$ converges at zero iff $\int_0^{\pi/2} g(x)\,dx$ converges.

Now $\int_0^{\pi/2} g(x)\,dx$ is a $p$-integral with exponent $p=m-1$.  We know those converge at $0$ whenever $p>-1$, equivalently $m>0$.

Now, look at the $\pi/2$ end.  Since $\lim_{x\to \pi/2^-} \cos(x) = 0$, there is a discontinuity if $n < 0$.  You can use a similar argument to show that $n>0$ is necessary and sufficient.  Note $\cos(x-\pi/2) = \sin x$.

Comment: And there is an analogous condition on $n$ since $\cos(\pi/2)=0$.

Comment: Oh, thanks, Mark.  I hadn't noticed that off the bat.

Comment: You're welcome Matthew.  My pleasure.

Comment: Answer edited to include reference to other end.

Comment: Matthew, (+1) ... but $\cos(x-\pi/2)=\sin(x)\ne -\sin(x)$. ;-)

Comment: Right again, Mark!